# Punctuation / Conjunctive Adverb question

Tags: punctuation, adverbs

Just double checking my old brain. Does the phrase "more specifically" in the sentence below operate as a conjunctive adverb and thus need punctuation? I feel certain there's a comma after "specifically", but I would also like to recall the grammar term. Thanks

"Olivia Mellan made many observations about the different views people have on money and more specifically how these views can affect a relationship between a male and female in a negative way."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the phrase is a conjunctive adverb. And it DOES need to be offset by commas, not just after it, but in front of it as well:

> Olivia Mellan made many observations about the different views people
>   have on money **and, more specifically,** how these views can affect a
>   relationship between a male and [a] female in a negative way.